# php odbc result unsetting

Tags: php, odbc

So, here's my issue: I have a function that queries sql and pulls it into a resource. In this function, I run:

```
 if (odbc_num_rows($rs) === 0) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        if ($type !== "Issues") {
            while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
                $issues['tvi'][] = odbc_result($rs, 'TitleVolumeIssue_c_');
            }
        }
        return $rs;
    }
```

This does exactly what it is supposed to do. However, when I pass $rs into the next method for parsing into html, it seems as though $rs gets unset. Oddly, I can call odbc_num_rows($rs) and it gives me the correct number of rows, but dumping the var shows it is false and I can't loop through the resource to get any values.

How can I either free up that resource so that it can be used in the next function or how can I rewrite the IF condition so that I get the values without unsetting the resource?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each time you fetch it moves the database cursor to the next row.

So `odbc_fetch_row()` keeps going to the next row, until the last one. After that it returns false.

Unfortunately you cannot move the row pointer back to the first record.

You will have to query your `DB` one more time.

Comment: the issues array holds a set of data I am extracting from the resource, but that gets used elsewhere, elsewhen. The resource is what I need to pass to the next function so that I an loop through the resource and extract out all of the data that I need.

Comment: ok I see what you mean, this will not work. when you return `rs` after the loop the ressource is unset. Your alternative is to query the db again.

Comment: returning the $rs works fine outside of the loop, but if I run the loop, it's unset. Would setting the cursor back to row 1 keep it set you think?

Comment: yes it works outside of the loop because you don't fetch any row. You cant set pointer back to 1 odbc library isnt that sophisticated. for example mysql has [mysql_data_seek](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

Comment: screw it, I'll just tack on $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql); again outside of the loop, but inside of the condition and set the resource again.

Comment: Thanks for the info Meda. If you change your comments to your answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @VikingBlooded Ok I adjusted the answer

Comment: Thanks. I was bashing my head for hours trying to figure out why I could get odbc_num_rows($rs) to work but otherwise, any while loop returned false. Makes total sense now though, unsettling as it may be.

Comment: Sometimes querying the database can take a long time and doing it multiple times can get crazy! See my answer if you're dealing with a lot of data and a fast load time is important.

Answer (score -1):

Another option for this would be to store the odbc result in an array that you can loop through using a foreach. This preserves the data and you only have to query once vs multiple times (helps when dealing with a lot of data).

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $resultsArray[] = $row;
}
```

Then loop through it like this...

```
foreach ($resultsArray as $key=>$value){
    //Do what you need to do...
}
```

I had a similar problem in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328974/php-how-to-prevent-discarding-of-an-odbc-result-set) and [@Jeff Puckett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4233593/jeff-puckett) was able to explain it pretty well.

Comment: Which in turn makes the answer different. I provided code and I also provided a way to hold onto that information for further data handling in case querying the database again was not an option.